# C++ cin and cout not showing in console

Tags: c++, inheritance, iostream

I have started out a game project with some friends and we try to work out why our class is not displaying any output. We have included SDL 2.0 (just so you know, in case it matters)

The problem is that we have a class which inherits and stuff...

```
class Tile {
private:
    int textureId;
public:
    Tile();
    Tile(int texId);
    ~Tile();

    void Print_Data();
}

class Tile_Gun : public Tile {
private:
    int damage;
public:
    Tile_Gun();
    Tile_Gun(int texId, int dmg);
    ~Tile_Gun();

    void Print_Data();
}
```

That is the base setup. And I want to run Print_Data() for both.
I create a object in main() and I have set breakpoints to control the data, which all seems to stop and fill the expected areas. But when it launches the Print_Data() function it stops at the couts and cins in the breakpoints (it runs it) but nothing is added to the console.

What is going on, and if you need more info, just tell me... (Thought I'd keep it as short as I could for now)

How I call the class:

```
int texId = 0, dmg = 5;
Tile_Gun testgun = Tile_Gun(texId, dmg);
//The 0 passed to the parent constructor with Tile::Tile(texId)
testgun.Print_Data();
```

EDIT:

```
void Tile::Print_Data() {
    int dummy;
    cout << "My texId is: " << textureId;
    cin >> dummy;
}

void Tile_Gun::Print_Data() {
    int dummy;
    cout << "My damage is: " << damage;
    cin >> dummy;
}
```

Comment: Seems more sensible to me to do `Tile_Gun testgun(texId, dmg); std::cout << testgun;`.

Comment: Where are the cins and couts in the above code?

Comment: I added the cins and couts at the bottom =)

Comment: Add a new line: `cout << "stuff" << endl;`  The console is most likely line-buffered by default.

Comment: in main() right before i call the Print_Data()?
EDIT: No matter where, it doesn't show up!

Comment: No, whenever you're printing stuff.  Sorry, I'll use your example:  `cout << "My damage is: " << damage << endl;`

Comment: Does it give some error? throwing exception? or simply not displaying cin/cout related stuff in console?

Comment: No errors, it just doesn't show up. Also I should mention that I use Visual Studio 2012, if that matters.

Comment: Does your program start up as a console program?  If it doesn't, and you allocate the console manually, you'll have to pipe the standard input/output handles to the console.

Comment: The program starts up an SDL window with an image saying "Hello world" but there is no console window before I call system("pause");

Comment: I found the answer now!
My project was not set to run a separate console window. That is why only system("pause") showed up...

My solution was:

    Project settings -> Linker -> SubSystem = Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a problem regarding **iostream** in your code. Here's how i tried to run your code, & it worked perfectly. check out your constructors and destructors. make sure constructors implementation. refer to following code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Tile {
protected:
int textureId;
public:
Tile(){
}
Tile(int texId)
{
    textureId = texId;
}
// ~Tile();
void Print_Data();

};

void Tile::Print_Data() {
int dummy;
cout << "My texId is: " << textureId;
cin >> dummy;
}

class Tile_Gun : public Tile {
private:
int damage;
public:
Tile_Gun()
{

}
Tile_Gun(int texId, int dmg)
{
    damage = dmg;
    textureId = texId;
}
//  ~Tile_Gun();

void Print_Data();
};
void Tile_Gun::Print_Data() {
int dummy;
cout << "My damage is: " << damage<<endl;
cin >> dummy;
cout<<"I have taken input: "<<dummy<<endl;
}





int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
int texId = 0, dmg = 5;
Tile_Gun testgun = Tile_Gun(texId, dmg);
//The 0 passed to the parent constructor with Tile::Tile(texId)
testgun.Print_Data();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I found the answer now!
My project was not set to run a separate console window. That is why only system("pause") showed up...

My solution was:

    Project settings -> Linker -> SubSystem = Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)

Comment: @AleksanderFimreite Yea, that could be the problem too. but this should give **error LNK2019**, and you said, it's not giving any error, when i asked earlier.

Comment: Well, that's how it was... Why it didn't give me an error, I don't know. But this was the solution ;)